# 3 Variable Limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I cannot seem to solve this 3-variable limit:
$$
{\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)}}\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
$$
I searched this up on symbolab and it said to convert to polar coordinates. However they immediately set z equal to r which doesn't make sense to me. If there is a 3rd variable I thought I had to convert it to cylindrical coordinates, but I still can't just let z = r or can I? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Presumably they meant spherical coordinates.

Comment: Use the AM-GM inequality to estimate the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

The function is symmetric with respect to interchange of variables, so you can take your limit as follows:

$$\lim\limits_{q \to 0} \frac{q^6}{3 q^2} = \lim\limits_{q \to 0} \frac{q^4}{3} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem without spherical coordinates: Since $|2xy|\leq x^2+y^2$ also $|2xy|\leq x^2+y^2+z^2$, and hence also $\dfrac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$
Therefore
$$0 \leq |f(x,y,z)| \leq \dfrac{|xyz^2|}{2}$$
after which the limits becomes obviously zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the definition of a limit. We claim that the limit in question is zero. Indeed, fix $\varepsilon > 0$. It suffices to show that there is $\delta > 0$ such that
$$0<|{\bf r}|<\delta\implies \left\lvert\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}-0\right\rvert<\varepsilon,\text{ where ${\bf r}=(x,y,z)$ }$$
Observe that
$$\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leqslant \frac{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=|{\bf r}|^4$$
Thus, we can take $\delta = \varepsilon^{1/4}$, and the claim is proved.

Answer (score 0):

$$L={\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)}}\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
Since $x^2 \le x^2+y^2+z^2$ we have :
$$0 \leq \left|\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right| \leq {(yz)^2}$$
$$\implies L=0$$